# jcarousel, I need :active state on external controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am running a Jcarousel and I want to add a.active to the current pagination option. I have seen other posts around about this same thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * We use the initCallback callback
 * to assign functionality to the controls
 */
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
        return false;
    });
}

jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.next();
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.prev();
    return false;
});
};

// Ride the carousel...
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        // This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
});
</script>
```

Thats the initialize code

and the pagination lives inside:

```
<ul class="jcarousel-control">
    <%  (1..@project.size).each do |n| %>
        <li><a href="#"><%= n %></a></li>
    <% end %> 
</ul>`
```

Its a rails app, so rails is creating the list based on the number of projects in the group.

Any ideas?  Seems like it should be pretty simple..  But I don't know js at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I figured out apiece of this on my own. First if you simply provide

```
 ul.jcarousel-control li a:focus {background-position:0 -11px}
```

This sets the current control item to be "on"

This doesn't work though until its clicked.

Answer (score 10):

I also needed this and finally found a solution, here is my code:

```
jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        // This tells jCarousel NOT to autobuild prev/next buttons
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: {
            onAfterAnimation: function(c, o, i, s) {
            --i;
              jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
              jQuery('.jcarousel-control a:eq('+i+')').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
            }
          }
    });
```

Comment: If you're using a circular rotation, you'll want to use 

`i = (i - 1) % $('#mycarousel li').size();` instead of `--i;`

Comment: Brilliant solution! Worked without alteration using `wrap: 'last'`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `var size = c.options.size; i = (((i - 1) % size) + size) % size;` instead of `--i;`. This code fixes the modulus of negative values.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Been pulling my hair out for half a day to get the second around incremented indexes to highlight the correct external control :)